# Identify Chopin Prelude or Rondo from sheet music snippet

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, piano

I found this snippet of a piece in a box, and it's really frustrating me that I don't know what it is. It's clearly written for piano, and judging by the publication information at the bottom, it's by Chopin and is from "Preludes and Rondos, Op.28, 45, 1, 5, 16" (source: IMSLP). I can't seem to figure out what it is; does anyone recognize it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Chopin's Prelude in B-flat minor, Op. 28, No. 16. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbU_N102vIY) a video where it's performed just plain too damn fast.

Comment: That link is now dead. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LmH18JCfnI) is a video of a performance by Yevgeny Kissin, with the score.